# Android popup menu customize menu item (padding, text size etch.)

Tags: android, customization, padding, popupmenu

I am implementing a popup menu for my android application. I want to be able to customize the items of the menu and change the default values (for the item padding, margin, padding between item icons etch.). Currently i am able to change only the text color and size of each item with the properties:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

which are set within :

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
```

How is this possible, which attributes i need to set in the styling of the menu?

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, You can create customized layout specifically for the popup and you can give each items different margin padding..**

Check out below code.

```
 private fun createPopUp() {
        val popUpView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null)
       val  mpopup = PopupWindow(
            popUpView, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true
       )
       
        popUpView.close.setOnClickListener{
            mpopup.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the popup layout you can create a separate XML for that and add layout and items into that with each attributes available within.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```